# How to show power in RichtextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, math, pow

How to show real face of power in rich text box like this photo? Would someone provide some code or an example?

[image]

Comment: You should probably do some research into the RTF format.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Display_of_Power

Answer (score 1):

Just read the [example in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncharoffset.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Lucinda Console", 12);
        // Set the baseline text.
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = "x";
        // Set the CharOffset to display superscript text.
        richTextBox1.SelectionCharOffset = 10;
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Lucinda Console", 8);
        // Set the superscripted text.  
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = "2x";
        // Reset the CharOffset to display text at the baseline.
        richTextBox1.SelectionCharOffset = 0;
```

Comment: **NB** The value you use for SelectionCharOffset will be dependent on the font size when you set the SelectionFont.  E.g. if your font size is 48 point, the SelectionCharOffset of 10 wouldn't be enough; you'd want something more like 44.  Experiment with the numbers till you get the look you want.